# Eclipse Error for WildFly: org/xnio/Cancellable : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: java, eclipse, wildfly, jboss-tools

I installed WildFly 8.2.1 in `D:\SOURCE\ProgramsInstalled\wildfly-8.2.1.Final` directory. I test ran it outside of Eclipse and it is working perfect.

I installed Eclipse Luna in `D:\SOURCE\ProgramsInstalled\eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-win32-x86_64` directory.

Inside Eclipse Luna, I set JDK 1.7 as the default JRE:

[image]

Inside Eclipse Luna, I installed `JBoss Tools 4.2.3.Final` plugin via Eclipse Marketplace.

Inside Eclipse Luna, I installed WildFly 8.x runtime environment pointing to the WildFly in `D:\SOURCE\ProgramsInstalled\eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-win32-x86_64` directory. And created the WildFly 8.x server using this runtime.

Inside Eclipse Luna, I ran WildFly. The "Console" view of Eclipse is showing me that WildFly ran successfully but Eclipse give me this error message:

[image]

Why I am getting this error? And how to resolve it?

When I try to stop WildFly in Eclipse I get this error message:

[image]

And Eclipse would not let me stop the WildFly. Not good. I am stuck.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error you get when you've compiled your code with Java 7, yet try to run it on a JRE of an older version (Java 6, for instance).

You can solve this in two ways:

1. re-compile the code in the version you want to run it in
2. update the jre you'll run the code in to (at least) the version you compiled your code with

Comment: Inside Eclipse, I dont have any code in the Wokspace i.e. no projects; I have set Java 1.7 as the default JRE (just updated the OP with its picture). So why I am getting this error when I dont have any code?

Comment: the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable was set to JDK 1.6. I set it to JDK 1.7. Restart Eclipse. Run the WildFly and I did not get the error message. Cheers.